# Programmatically Ignore Cout

Tags: c++, cout, ostream

Does anybody know if there is a trick to toggle all the `cout <<` functions to not print out visible output? I am trying to hack together some code written by me and some other people to put together a demo. I would rather not redirect the output to a file and would like a solution that had some measure of compatibility between Windows and Linux.

In my scenario I have many many lines of code with with various `#defines` controlling when certain methods produce debug output. I want to call something like:

```
cout.off();
driverForAffectA();
driverForAffectB();
cout.on();
printSpecializedDebug();
exit(0);
```

Comment: Well, you can always redirect your output to a file or dev/null!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change cout's stream buffer.

```
streambuf *old = cout.rdbuf();
cout.rdbuf(0);
cout << "Hidden text!\n";
cout.rdbuf(old);
cout << "Visible text!\n";
```

Edit:

Thanks to John Flatness' comment you can shorten the code a bit:

```
streambuf *old = cout.rdbuf(0);
cout << "Hidden text!\n";
cout.rdbuf(old);
cout << "Visible text!\n";
```

Comment: Even better, `rdbuf(streambuf*)` returns the old buffer, so you don't even need separate calls to get the old one and set a new one.

Comment: @John Flatness: Oh thanks I didn't notice that in the docs. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why precisely do you not want to redirect the output?  If it is because there is *other* output you wish to keep, you may be out of luck.

If it is just so you don't have to type a complex shell expression on a terminal in a demo, I suggest making a start script and doing the redirect inside.

That, or reopen stdout to `/dev/null` somewhere near the top of main.