# Optionally print to stdout at runtime

Tags: c++, stdout

I have output in a C++ program that I only want to see if a "verbose" option is specified at runtime. I've found lots of methods to use preprocessor `#define` statements to control debugging output when compiling, but I can't find any ways to do this at runtime short of wrapping every `cout` in `if(verbose)`.

In pseudocode, I'd like to transform:

```
if(verbose)
  cout << "Some text: " << variable << endl;
...
if(verbose)
  cout << "Other text: " << var << endl;
```

Into:

```
if(verbose)
  //block cout

cout << "Some text: " << variable << endl;
cout << "Other text: " << var << endl;
```

Is there some way to optionally redefine cout at runtime so those lines silently print nothing? Better yet would be a more flexible approach that allows some output while blocking others.

Comment: `cout` is character out, distinguished from `wcout` (wide-character out).  It is not "console".  Do not conflate stdout with a tty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721026/programatically-ignore-cout :-)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't fully understand the distinction you're making. This is a program that runs in a terminal and any cout statements appear in the terminal (which I understand to be stdout). Should the question begin "I have tty output..."?

Comment: Your question talks about "console output".  But there is nothing related to a 'console' anywhere in your code unless you mistakenly assume that stdout is a console.  I am pointing out that it is a mistake to think that stdout is a console.

Comment: @jake It depends on the system.  At least under Unix and Windows, regardless of where the program runs, there is no assurance that `std::cout` goes to the console; both systems support pipes and redirection.

Comment: @jake Which, of course, is the logical answer to your question.  Under Windows, just invoke the program with `prog >nul`; under Unix, with `prog >/dev/null`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: considering the OP's requirements, I think you mean `2>nul` and (if this notation works in Unix-land) `2>/dev/null`. That takes care of `std::clog`. Among others.

Comment: @Alf I don't know what the OP's requirements are (although I suspect that an explicitly opened file would be most appropriate), but his question concerned `std::cout` (and the notation originated in Unix-land; I was using it when Windows was still MS-DOS version 1).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I was referring to "Better yet would be a more flexible approach that allows some output while blocking others.". Which could be done by having all the verbose output going to `std::clog`. In which case redirection of that to thebbbits (the big bit bucket in the sky) would remove the verbosity and leave the kernel output. But evidently I misunderstood you. Or the OP. :-)

Comment: @JamesKanze and Alf - I'm trying to limit cout statements in class methods invoked from main. I don't want to redirect the entire program into a file or /dev/null.

Comment: @JamesKanze and William: I said console because I knew I wasn't redirecting or piping stdout. Question edited to remove "console." Does this make the question correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply bind a stream object reference to different streams depending on `verbose`:

```
ostream& vout = (verbose? cout : nullstream);
```

Then use `vout` for all the output that should only appear when `verbose`.

Of course you need to define `nullstream` first; that involves [defining a `streambuf` derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200207/redirect-debug-output-to-null-stream-instead-of-stdcerr).

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but I have to digest the information about defining nullstream.

Comment: @jake: actually [James Kanze has answered that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243743/is-there-a-null-stdostream-implementation-in-c-or-libraries) (I didn't notice when I wrote the above), and there's also a Ready To Use™ implementation in Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're in the process of writing a program, or whether you already have a program you want to disable output for. Generally, when you're writing software with debugging output, you'll want to create some sort of logging class to help you control when output occurs and where it goes (e.g., to a file, to stdout, to stderr, etc.). An example of a simple one would be:

```
#include <iostream>

class Logger {

public:
    Logger(bool enabled) : enabled(enabled) { }
    void setEnabled(bool enabled) { this->enabled = enabled; }

    template<typename T> Logger& operator<<(T const& t)
    {
        if (enabled)
            std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }

    // If you'd like manipulator support (e.g., for std::endl)
    Logger& operator<<(std::ostream& (*manipulator)(std::ostream&))
    {
        if (enabled)
            std::cout << manipulator;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    bool enabled;
};

int main()
{
    Logger log(true);
    log << "Hello, " << "World!" << 123; // Prints Hello, World!123

    log.setEnabled(false);
    log << "Hello, " << "World!" << 123; // Prints nothing
}
```

Alternatively, you could redirect cout, as others have mentioned, or even just simply redirect your program's output to /dev/null on the command line:

```
./myProgram > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing that @Cheersandhth.-Alf. For sure; looks good! Just going to add a comment indicating what that part is for, in case OP or any new readers aren't familiar with it.