# Programmatically Ignore printf

Tags: c++, printf

I'm using someones library that printf's out an error message when a connection to a device is unsuccessful.
The library code prints out nothing when a connection is successful.

I periodically check (loop & sleep) to see if a device is connected but I only want to print out when it is connected.

**At the moment I get something like:**

```
Waiting for connection... (<-- My print)
Error
Error
Error
Error
Error
Connection successful (<-- My print)
```

**What I want is:**

```
Waiting for connection... (<-- My print)
Connection successful (<-- My print)
```

**How can I programatically ignore a printf?**

N.b. I found a similar question [Programmatically Ignore Cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721026/programatically-ignore-cout) but that solution  did not work for printf.

**I am using Windows.**

Can anyone help? (c/c++ novice)

Comment: I guess this question could fall under several tags c, c# maybe? Can someone edit if that is the case? (I've only had experience with c & c++)

Comment: @Ke​​​​​​​​​​​​vin: No, tag the language you're actually using, not every language that supports console output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13816994/560648?

Comment: I guess I want to try close the stdout AND reopen it later

Comment: On POSIX, you can use `dup2` to redirect `printf`, and on most Unixes, that redirection can go nowhere via `/dev/null`. However, there is not a standard C++ way.

Comment: @KevinPaton: At least [one answer there shows you how to do exactly that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817208/560648).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like (before establishing connection):

```
FILE * myout = stdout;
stdout = fopen ("standard-output-file", "w");
```

To print something to output you could use then:

```
fprintf(myout, "format", ...);
```

**Edit:** Remember to close the file descriptor afterwards:

```
fclose(myout);
```

Comment: I am not wanting to print to a file (if I have understood you correctly), I am wanting to programatically ignore printfs temporarily.

Comment: @KevinPaton Yes but you could open e.g. /dev/null as an output if you are in Linux that would be equivalent with ignoring it...

Comment: @KevinPaton on the other hand everything written to `myout` would be shown in standard output as expected...

Comment: It's implementation defined (not everywhere stdout is an assignable FILE*). For example (on Windows) current MSVC++ implementation changed to define stdout as return value of a function (actually function returns an array).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working under Linux the following way

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   printf("Start\n");
   freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
   printf("middle\n");
   freopen("/dev/stdin", "w", stdout);  // really stdin here!
   printf("End\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Under Windows I think there are other names for files (`nul` and `con` maybe).

However, this seems to be completely unportable, and, what's worse, this will prevent the users from redirecting your program output to a file, because I explicitly reopen `/dev/stdin`. There are suggestions that you can use `/dev/fd/1` instead of `/dev/stdin` to mitigate the latter problem, but I have not tested it.

It seems that there is no reliable way, see, e.g. http://c-faq.com/stdio/undofreopen.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817208/153285 should be reliable, and about as portable as this.

Comment: You could also redirect stdio by wrapping the program executeable in a bash/batch script.

Comment: It's implementation defined (not everywhere stdout is an assignable FILE*). Moreover OP has to do it in Windows...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the absolute solution, but you'll need to use:

```
freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
```

Or something similar, but with **"conout$"** pseudo-file, which I believe is same as `/dev/stdout` on Linux.

You may have to use `GetStdHandle`, `AttachConsole` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++11 and above you can use a simple variadic template without much coding so this overloads `printf` for all cases and the original one never gets called

```
template <typename ...Args>
void printf(Args... ...)
{
}
```

Comment: It won't work in 3rd party library (unless they're doing printf in their headers).

Comment: unless he can recompile it. anyway I gave a shot.